# Prove $\iint_R f_{xy}(x,y)=f(a,c)-f(a,d)+f(b,d)-f(b,c)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I'm asked to show that if $f_{xy}$ is Riemann Integrable on $R$, then

$$\iint_R f_{xy}(x,y)=f(a,c)-f(a,d)+f(b,d)-f(b,c)$$

Where $R=[a,b]\times[c,d]$.

To do this I can use the following formulation of Fubini's theorem:

> If $f:R=[a,b]\times[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, and for each $x\in[a,b]$ the function $h(y)=f(x,y)$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[c,d]$ then
>   $$\iint_R f=\int_a^b\int_c^d f\ dy dx$$

So this seems like it's a straight forward exercise. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how we can conclude that indeed $f_{xy}(x,y)$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[c,d]$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Because there are plenty of functions for which their derivative is not Riemann integrable. So I'm not seeing why we are allowed to use Fubini's theorem here, given that we are working with this specific formulation.

Thanks.

---

So just to be clear: my question is:

> How does $f_{xy}$ being Riemann integrable on $R$ imply that for each $x\in[a,b]$ the function $h(y)=f_{xy}(x,y)$ is Riemann integrable on on the interval $[c,d]$.

Note we make no explicit assumptions of continuity or anything else.

Comment: The assumption is that the mixed partial is Riemann Integrable.

Comment: If the function is differentiable, it is continuous and therefore ...

Comment: $f$ has a mixed partial that is RI.  So, $f$ is continuous.  Continuity is sufficient for RI